# How do I buy a specific number of potions?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can I buy a specific number of potions at once, or am I forced to buy them one at a time?

Comment: Who needs potions? :)  They seem pretty useless in this game.

Comment: @EBongo Potions are far from useless, they have got me out of a lot of tough situations.

Comment: @EBongo Just wait until you hit the harder difficulties.

Comment: Figured it might be something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any method to buy multiple potions at once. The Shift+Click method which allows you to build stacks of specific size of some items in your inventory / chest (gems, potions, …) does not work when buying something. Other modifiers don't seems to work as well, so you need to resort to right clicking like a madman.

Comment: `so you need to resort to right clicking like a madman.` - Fortunately, this is Diablo. You should be used to that anyway.